# Angular Meteor - Blaze is not defined

Tags: angularjs, meteor, meteor-blaze

I want to use blaze from my angular controller, similar use as 
https://github.com/dotansimha/accounts-ui-angular/blob/master/login-buttons-directive.js

```
 Blaze.render(Template.loginButtons, element[0]);
```

When I try that from my own directive I get - "ReferenceError: Blaze is not defined".

My angular app decleration includes angular-meteor and I also tried to call angular-blaze-template but it's still not being recognized.

I'm not sure why it's working on accounts-ui-angular directive and not on mine